# How to use a GridView in a submission form that stores data to an xml file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, gridview

I have a submission form that stores data into an XML file via button click. A new XML file is created each time the user clicks the submit button. In the form, I’m also using an editable GridView (**id = gvProductNumber**) that writes its data to the same XML file. My problem is that when the user clicks the submit button, the data submitted via the textbox controls are written to the xml file, but the data from the editable Gridview does not remain. Thus I'm left with just the data submitted from the textbox controls.

This is my code -**button click**- snippet used for storing the data submitted via the textbox controls -it writes the user's  first and last name to the xml file along with the product ID and Product number.

```vb
Public Sub Write_XML(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim textWriter As New XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataV.xml"), Nothing)
    textWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented
    'Start New Document
    textWriter.WriteStartDocument()
    'Write a Comment
    textWriter.WriteComment("This is a comment")
    'Insert Start Element -root element node
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("PersonalData")
    'write the child element
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("products")
    'write the child element
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("product")
    'Write ProductID Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("productID", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtProductID.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'Write ProductID Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("productNumber", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtProductNum.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'write the child element
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("customers")
    'write the child element
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("customer")
    'Write LastName Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("LastName", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtLastName.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'Write FirstName Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("FirstName", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtFirstName.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'End Everything
    textWriter.WriteEndDocument()
    'Clean up
    textWriter.Flush()
    textWriter.Close()
    'Display the XML Document
    Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataV.xml"))
End Sub
```

The Gridview is using the typical Insert/Edit/Delete Functionality to write to the xml file. Is there a way I can implement the ID of the Editable Gridview or the Textboxes being used in the Gridview into the above Snippt? When I try using the textbox ids of the Gridview as an argument of WriteString as  I did with the textbox controls, I get an error stating that they are not declared.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `DataTable` and add it to a `DataSet` you use the [Dataset.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) method. Conversely, you can reload the data with the [DataSet.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx) method.

The `Gridview` displays the data from the `DataTable` if it is set as it's `DataSource`.

Comment: Sorry, if I'm not fully understanding your answer, however - I'm able to successfully read and write the data of the GridView to the XML file; the problem is, upon submitting the form via the submit button, which functions off the code snippet I provided, the data from the Gridview is overwritten with the data inputted via the textboxes. Am aiming to keep both the data from the GridView and textboxes in the XML file upon clicking the submit button. Currenly, after the form is submitted, only the data from the Textboxes remain.

Comment: Create a new dataTable and add some columns to it, fill it with some rows of data, use the method I showed you above and you will see the xml that it creates for you.

Comment: ok, I understand - I'm in the process of implementing the approach - Thanks